# Android - Activity force finish when launch other Application that crashes on launch

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an button in an Activity, clicking on it will start a service in the background which tries to launch some predefined application via using it's launch intent.
The problem is, if the next application gets crashed when my service launches it, it force finishes my Activity too.

Logs:

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.crashapp, PID: 31064
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.crashapp/com.example.crashapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
   ...

W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.example.crashapp/.MainActivity 
// some sample App that crashes in onCreate.
...
W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity <my_package>/.ui.activities.MyActivity
//My application's activity
```

The query is how to fix my activity so that it will stop getting finished in this scenario.

Comment: post your `MainActivity` Code

Comment: I think the only solution for your problem is to fix the null pointer exception

Comment: crashapp is just a dummy App, which has only one Activity MainActivity.java which "throw new NullPointerException()" on the very first line of onCreate().
@dijish, the NPE is not on my application, my application launches some other application which crashes on launch. This not only finishes that application's activity but my activity too.

Comment: post the code that launches the other app

Comment: Then how is this crashapp is running

Comment: Any update, I also meet this issue

Comment: Any update, i also facing the same